# Require File Lua

Tags: lua

How can I run a function from another file on same directory?

Example:

file1:

```
function sleep(n)
  local t = os.clock()
  while os.clock() - t <= n do
    -- nothing
  end
end
```

file2:

```
dofile('/barboszalib.lua')

function DoSomething(target)
print(target + 3)
end

while true do
DoSomething(4)
barboszalib.sleep(5)
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*file1* defines a *global* function named `sleep`. So you have to call `sleep(5)` in *file2*.

`barboszalib.sleep(5)` fails because there is no table named `barboszalib`.

If you want to make *file1* into a library, do this:

*file1*:

```
local M={}

function M.sleep(n)
  local t = os.clock()
  while os.clock() - t <= n do
    -- nothing
  end
end

return M
```

and the in *file2* do

```
local barboszalib=dofile('/barboszalib.lua')
...
barboszalib.sleep(5)
```

If you want `require` instead of `dofile`, do this:

```
local barboszalib=require('barboszalib')
```

but make sure Lua can find it in `LUA_PATH` or `package.path`.